# Faster database access by index

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.android

I have this code

```
using (var contents = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    contents.CommandText = "SELECT [subject],[note] FROM tasks";
    var r = contents.ExecuteReader();
    int zaehler = 0;
    int zielzahl = 5;
    while (r.Read())
    {
        if (zaehler == zielzahl)
        {
            //access r["subject"].ToString()
        }
        zaehler++;
    }
}
```

I want to make it faster by accessing zielzahl directly like r[zielzahl] instead of iterating through all entries. But

```
r[zielzahl]["subject"]
```

does not work aswell as

```
r["subject"][zielzahl]
```

How do I access the column *subject* of result number *zielzahl*?

Answer (score 0):

To get only the sixth record, use the [`OFFSET` clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby):

```
SELECT subject, note
FROM tasks
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5
```

Please note that the order of returned records is not guaranteed unless you use the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Same as previously, only you get one record now, so you don't have to count.